# Use a variable inside a variable in Smarty 2 template

Tags: smarty, smarty2

I am trying to use a smarty variable inside a smarty variable in a template.

The following will work in smarty 3 but not in smarty 2:

```
{$_content_{$id}.content_title}
```

to display for example:

```
{$_content_10.content_title}
```

In smarty 2 it only throws an error. Is there any way to do this in smarty 2?

Comment: _In smarty 2 it only throws an error. Is this in smarty 2 possible?_ if it throws an error then its not possible - what is the error message?

Comment: The error is: Fatal error: Smarty error: [in content.html line 4]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $_content_{$id (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 449) in Smarty.class.php on line 1095

Comment: seems like it is not possible in the lower versions - read over their changelogs

Comment: I know... Maybe there is another way to get the content

Comment: maybe you do it in php before data comes to the template